# Build Error: _CollectBundleResources does not exist in the project

Tags: macos, maui

I have no idea what caused this problem because I don't use the Mac often, but after the latest Visual Studio updates, my Windows-MacOS Maui project experienced a "_CollectBundleResources" error when trying to Build on Mac -- it previously worked just fine on both platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Source of the problem identified in csproj:

OutputType 'WinExe' needs to change to just 'Exe'.